# Unable to turn on Multi-Dex in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

i was getting java.exe exited error previously in my xamarin android project but after enabling multi dex i am getting this weird kind of error. Can anyone help me in finding the solution for it?

Here is the error

```
             MultiDexMainDexListFile: obj\Debug\multidex.keep
            1>    CustomMainDexListFiles:
            1>    ToolExe: mainDexClasses.bat
            1>    ToolPath: C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\\
            1>    ProguardHome: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\
            1>  Environment Variables passed to tool:
            1>    PROGUARD_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\
            1>    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
            1>  C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\\mainDexClasses.bat --output obj\Debug\multidex.keep "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Common\library_project_imports\bin\Common.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Data\library_project_imports\bin\Data.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Gauges\library_project_imports\bin\Gauges.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Input\library_project_imports\bin\Input.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.List\library_project_imports\bin\List.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Primitives\library_project_imports\bin\Primitives.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\TwilioClient.Android\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\TwilioClient.Android\library_project_imports\libs\org.apache.http.legacy.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Firebase.Common\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks\library_project_imports\classes.jar';'C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'obj\Debug\android\bin\classes'" 
            1>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : error : Unknown option '[2598:39D0][2016-11-22T22:11:15]i001:' in line 1 of file 'C:\Users\Muhammad',
            1>    included from argument number 13
            1>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
            1>  Invalid option 
            1>  Usage:
            1>  
            1>  Short version: Don't use this.
            1>  
            1>  Slightly longer version: This tool is used by mainDexClasses script to build
            1>  the main dex list.
            1>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
            1>  The command exited with code -1.
            1>Done executing task "CreateMultiDexMainDexClassList" -- FAILED.
            1>Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "VoipApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
            1>
            1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: I'd probably disable multi-dex and focus on the original problem you were having. I don't quite know why you would need mutli-dex, does your app have over 65k methods?

Answer (score 0):

This Error usually occurs when your Android SDK path has spaces in between its path this is a known bug in Xamarin multidex and you can find related information [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70746/multi-dex-fails-because-of-space-in-android-sdk-in.html).

Now solving the issue is very easy, your current SDK path is something like this

`:C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Moving it to something like this would solve your issue for good:

`C:\Users\Android\android-sdk\`

Goodluck!
Revert if it does not work